# Making numbers easier to read using filters

Tags: python, flask

So I am trying to convert numbers on my website to look a bit nicer, such as `3217210` instead should be `3,217,210` I have tested a few threads but didn't get it to work.

My website takes these values from an API.

Heres my HTML:

```
<tbody>
      {% for product in products %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ product.id|replace("_", ' ')|lower()|title() }}</td>
        {% for buy in product.buy_price %}
        <td>{{ buy.pricePerUnit }}</td>
        {% for sell in product.sell_price %}
        <td>{{ sell.pricePerUnit }}</td>

        <td>{{ product.buy_volume|numberFormat }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.sell_volume}}</td>
        {% set margin = buy.pricePerUnit - sell.pricePerUnit%} {% set marginPer
        = margin/buy.pricePerUnit * 100%}
        <td
          aria-label="{{ marginPer|round(1, 'floor') }} % "
          data-balloon-pos="right"
        >
          {{ margin|round(1, 'floor')}}
        </td>
        {% endfor %}{% endfor %}
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

And here is my python:

```
@app.route('/bprices', methods=['GET'])
def bPrices():
    f = requests.get(
        'https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=[cant show]').json()
    products = [
        {
            "id": product["product_id"],
            "sell_price": product["sell_summary"][:1],
            "buy_price": product["buy_summary"][:1],
            "sell_volume": product["quick_status"]["sellVolume"],
            "buy_volume": product["quick_status"]["buyVolume"],
        }
        for product in f["products"].values()
    ]
    return render_template("bprices.html", products=products)
```

Thanks:)

Comment: are the numbers always in that format and do you always want the commas to after the first and fourth numbers? What is the filter `numberFormat` doing and where is the code for that?

Comment: forgot to remove that! Tried a filter on another thread, and it did not work. And yes, I want it to but `,`  after first number, and then the fourth. But not if it is `100`, would look a bit weird if it was `1,00`. Could say that numbers that are over 100 thousand could have `,`, so it looks like `100,000` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use global template filter in flask code and then use it in template. You can read the [official documentation on custom template filter](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#registering-filters).

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.template_filter()
def numberFormat(value):
    return format(int(value), ',d')


@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def home():
    products = [
        {
            "name": "mobile",
            "quantity": 3217210
        },
        {
            "name": "laptop",
            "quantity": 343217210
        },
        {
            "name": "mouse",
            "quantity": 100
        }        
    ]
    return render_template("index.html", products=products)
```

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Number format</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Products</h3>
    <table border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for product in products %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ product.quantity | numberFormat }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image: number formatter]

You can modify the filter as per your requirements.